# Confused about use of "data : " setting for jQuery .ajax()

Tags: jquery

Hey guys this is pretty simple - I ran across a cool MVC example at [Adam Wulf's site](http://welcome.totheinter.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-jquery/phase-1/p3/) and I'm trying to get a grip with how all the different pieces interact...  Within the model.js he has two different ways of using the **data : ** setting.  Can someone please explain the differences between the two of them, and maybe an example of a different method?  Code:

```
       $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data : { load : true },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 1000,
            error: function(){
                that.notifyLoadFail();
            },
            success: function(data){
                loadResponse(data);
                that.notifyLoadFinish();
            }
        });
```

Vs this example:

```
       $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data : { load : true, id : id },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 1000,
            error: function(){
                that.notifyLoadFail();
            },
            success: function(data){
                loadResponse(data);
                that.notifyLoadFinish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply an anonymous object used to pass values to the server.  In the first example, it contains a single value, "load":

```
data : { load : true }
```

In the 2nd, it has two values:

```
data : { load : true, id : id }
```

..."load" and "id".  Take the 2nd example: the server will receive two parameters for the request.  In PHP for example, you'd retrieve them with:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$load = $_GET['load'];
```

Make sense?

Cheers

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you.  I get it a lot more now... so actually the PHP file is like so:

<?
if(isset($_REQUEST["id"])){

Which I am now studying on, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The data is passed as an JSON-Object, which looks like this:

```
{ variable1: value1, variable2: value2 }
```

In the `ajax.php`-file, you access these variables with the `$_GET` variable:

```
$var1 = $_GET['variable1']  // = value1
$var2 = $_GET['variable2']  // = value2
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a good answer, but my noobie mind was having difficulty seeing the connnection...  I understand the first part, but was not understanding the second part because I didn't realize that $_GET is similar to $_REQUEST.  Nor did I understand the meaning of !isset

thank you for helping